# Webquerysave agents in lotus notes

Tags: lotus-notes, agent

In the WebQuerySave event of a form, we can add more than one agent. Is there any order in which the agents are called? Like the first agent is executed first and then the next?

Answer (score 3):

Agents are executed in formula's order.
Even `@PostedCommand(...)` lines **don't** get postponed after all `@Command(...)` lines. This is an exception for Webquerysave agents.

Comment: First agent gets executed first and then the second and so on - in same order like agent's calls written in formula.

Comment: If you really want to make sure that your code gets executed in the right order and you don't trust us, put your code in one agent and execute that one in the WebQuerySave.